# is `date` a valid mysql column name?

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema

I was wondering if `date` is actually a valid mysql column name?

According to the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html#table-reserved-words-new-5.5)

> MySQL permits some keywords to be used as unquoted identifiers because
>   many people previously used them. Examples are those in the following
>   list:
>
> - ACTION
> - BIT
> - DATE
> - ENUM
> - NO
> - TEXT
> - TIME
> - TIMESTAMP

So, from that I gather you are *allowed* to use `date` as a column name, but it doesn't say that it is *not recommended*.

So, are there any implications to using `date` as a column name?

Comment: yes, it's valid, but not particularly recommended, because it can/will cause confusion

Comment: But what if we have a table `games_played` I would put the columns as `id`. `home_team`, `away_team` `date`. In that instance the `date` column name makes sense, are there implications to using it here?

Comment: why not `dateplayed`? You may want to have multiple dates record, e.g. `datescheduled`, `dateupdated`, etc... `date` by itself would be rather ambiguous.

Comment: The only problem I encountered (running a database with columns named date myself) is the nuisance of always having to quote the column name when typing out a quick query, otherwise, mysql will complain about a syntax error. Apart from that, it's all fine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was able to add a column named `date` to the database, no quotes required.

So, yes, it's possible.

But you don't need to.  Choose another column name, e.g. `"date_recorded"`.  Not only is it better syntactically, but it's more descriptive.

Comment: I think calling it dumb is overly judgemental. If your table is named `game` and the column is named `date`, how is `game_date` more descriptive? `game.game_date` is just redundant.

Comment: game_date was a bad example, but being more descriptive is still a Good Thing.  How about "date_played", "date_recorded", or something that actually tells you what the column is for.

Comment: Did you have problems querying the `date` column?