# How to use OR & AND in WHERE clause in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to Mysql & have a table where at presently i'm fetching data as

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE name='$user' AND date='$selecteddate'
```

Now i want to add 1 more column named status_id where i want to select from to values i.e 1 or 2

I tried this query

```
 SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE (name='Ankit') AND (date='2015-04-23') AND (status_id='1' OR status_id='2')
```

but didn't work out.

Please help.

Comment: Is it showing any error

Comment: what's the data type of status_id column?

Comment: Seems to be query is ok. What you expect and what you getting?

Comment: I tried this in mysql & it gave error as "SELECT * FROM karmadetails WHERE (name='Ankit') AND (date='2015-04-23') AND (status_id='2' OR status_id='1')  "
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE (name='Ankit') AND (date='2015-04-23') AND (st' at line 1

Comment: If your first query working? what is the content of `$selecteddate` in your first query?

Comment: Please show the php code around the query.

Comment: how do you execute this query with php? the problem might be there....

Comment: I see a single and double quote at the beginning of your query, which doesn't look right

Comment: Data type is int. My initial query is working fine. $selecteddate is the date selected by the user.

Comment: I think you can change the column name 'date' to some other name 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775671/is-date-a-valid-mysql-column-name

Comment: So if type of status_id is int, you don't need the '. `status_id = 1`

Comment: it doesn't matter to use '' for datatype int

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you just need the elements concerned by the or clause to be between 
parenthesis.

They are not "needed", by the way (you could use precedence order of AND / OR), but I would say this is the best way for readability.

And if status_id data type is int, you don't need the `' '` around 1, and 2.

```
SELECT * 
 FROM tablename 
WHERE name='Ankit' 
AND date='2015-04-23' 
AND (status_id=1 OR status_id=2)
```

By the way, in this case, you may use an IN clause

```
AND status_id in (1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
"SELECT * FROM tablename 
 WHERE name='Ankit' 
 AND date='2015-04-23' 
 AND (status_id='1' OR status_id='2')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with using `IN`

```
AND status_id IN (1, 2)
```