# Trying to get a list of unique events from wp_posts with data from wp_postmeta

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've spent about 4 hours trying to figure out why I cannot do a group by of the post_title and left join the date data from the wp_postmeta table

The code without the group by clause, results all my events but I only want to retrieve the first instance of the event, by grouping by the post_title, which should give me the only first date in the string of classes to sign up for.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
SELECT posts.post_title,meta.date
    FROM wp_posts posts
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT meta_value AS date,post_id FROM wp_postmeta
            WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key ='_EventStartDate'
            ) meta
        ON posts.ID = meta.post_ID
WHERE posts.post_type='Tribe_Events' AND posts.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY posts.post_title
```

Comment: Probably not the root cause of your issue but still consider using a different name for the "date" column. Reasons why found here...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775671/is-date-a-valid-mysql-column-name/12785154

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate

Comment: And in this instance, a subquery is unnecessary

Comment: For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently `meta.date` is not in a `GROUP BY`, no math is performed on this field, and it is not part of a `DISTINCT` list of fields

It sounds like you want the first instance of `wp_postmeta.meta_value` for each `wp_posts.post_title`

If so, try this:

1. Ditch the subquery and resolve your `meta.meta_key` filter using [COALESCE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_coalesce.asp)
2. Use the [MIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_min.asp) function on `meta.meta_value`
3. If needed, [CAST](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_cast.asp) `meta.meta_value` as a datetime

Something like this maybe...harder to know without seeing the table structure and sample data.

```
SELECT posts.post_title
      ,MIN(CAST(meta.meta_value as DATETIME)) event_start_date 
  FROM wp_posts posts
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta meta
         ON posts.ID = meta.post_ID
WHERE posts.post_type ='Tribe_Events' 
  AND posts.post_status = 'publish'
  AND COALESCE(meta.meta_key, 'UNKNOWN') ='_EventStartDate'
GROUP BY posts.post_title;
```

This version can cope with multiple instances of `'_EventStartDate'` per `post_title`

Not sure if this is needed but it causes no harm. Just think of it as wearing a belt and suspenders.

Comment: I didn't do the downvote. But thank you for your attempt to help, your query did not result the way I expected it.

Comment: Your edit also gave me the desired result and you explained in detail what was happening. Thank you

Comment: @AlexBloom you are most welcome. I am glad to help.